# convert .htaccess to web.config on iis7

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, web.config-transform

```
first .htaccess in root
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

<Files *.ini>
require valid-user
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^lib(.*)$   ./lib/$1    [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$    ./public/$1.$2  [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  ./public/$1/    [L]
 </IfModule>

second .htaccess in /public/
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
```

i used rules import from iis7 but it's not work.
when i debug this, i feel that the second web.config does not read.
in my browser, my url is redirected to http://www.url.be/fr/ and i have error message 404.
to works, url is http://www.url.be/?page=fr

i'm lost!
Thanks
Guy